# SharePoint-Outlook Object Model, APIs

Tags: sharepoint, outlook

I wanted to know if there is any API available for doing some stuff in SharePoint and Outlook. Stuff like synchronizing between Outlook and SharePoint site, **Making entries in Meeting workspace related to a Outlook Meeting**.

I tried to search for it but couldn't get anything.

Any help/directions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is not.

There are a few things you can do with RSS feeds, or the 'Connect to Outlook' option, but there is no API as such.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do this using the SharePoint web services. Specifically the Lists.asmx web service. You can search for it online or find more information here to start.

http://www.infoq.com/articles/swanson-moss-web-services

In SharePoint 2010 - there might be some additional ways to accomplish this.

On the Outlook side you could do an add-in in multiple different ways and use these web services to interact with SharePoint